# How to add and delete an XML node?

Tags: c#, xml

I have this code below. I want to add a new node in it to hold more user records and if I want I can remove them. Can anyone help me?

```
string filename = "text.xml";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Login");
XmlElement id = doc.CreateElement("passWord");
root.SetAttribute("userName", nameTxb.Text);
id.SetAttribute("passWord", passwordTxb.Text);
XmlElement name = doc.CreateElement("UserName");
XmlElement passd = doc.CreateElement("PassWord");
name.InnerText = nameTxb.Text;
passd.InnerText = passwordTxb.Text;
root.AppendChild(name);
root.AppendChild(passd);
doc.AppendChild(root);
doc.Save(filename);
MessageBox.Show("Created SuccesFully!");
this.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XML document is stored in variable doc. You may use doc.SelectNodes() to select specified nodes using XPATH. You may also iterate over selected nodes and append childs, remove childs etc.

```
var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("xpath");
foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    //
}
```

Comment: same above code if i want to add the new line with new value how it works

Answer (score 0):

This will remove an element. You can keep using SelectSingleNode() to move down through the branches of the xml. element can also be selected that way - for this example, just consider it an arbitrary starting point.

```
someElement.RemoveChild(oDoc.SelectSingleNode("Parent").SelectSingleNode("Child"));
```

As far as I know, you can also use the same method at the XmlDocument level too.

Hope this helps.